# CoreLocation: Fence: onClientEventRegionState, invalid state

Tags: ios, xcode, core-location

I was testing an App viewing the logs in Xcode > Window > Devices and I found this lines:

```
Apr  1 17:09:33 myIphone locationd[2763] <Error>: Fence: requestRegionState,        com.myApp.demo/regionId, NOT FOUND
Apr  1 17:09:39 myIphone demo[3601] <Error>: CoreLocation: Fence:     onClientEventRegionState, invalid state, 0
```

These logs don't appear in the console if I run the App from Xcode. Also, the App works fine, but it's disturbing.

Has anyone found similar logs? What's the meaning of these logs?

Thank you all.

Answer (score 0):

I have seen this too in a Mac Catalyst app

```
2019-09-20 19:49:39.046086-0500 App[83029:4135201] [Generic_deprecated] Fence: CLClientRequestRegionState, unsupported fence type
2019-09-20 19:49:39.046548-0500 App[83029:4135201] [Generic_deprecated] Fence: CLClientRequestRegionState, unsupported fence type
2019-09-20 19:49:39.046922-0500 App[83029:4135201] [Generic_deprecated] Fence: CLClientRequestRegionState, unsupported fence type
```